# Post value dynamically inside wsdl structure

Tags: php, curl, wsdl

I have the php scrip to post and update value for the wsdl key using curl php:

```
 $imei = $_POST['86207503'];   
    $data = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:sub=\"http://subscriberexample.com/\">\r\n
      <soap:Header/>\r\n   <soap:Body>\r\n
      <sub:wsUpdateSubscriberProfile>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <subscriberProfile>\r\n
      <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->\r\n
      <entry>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <key>IMEI</key>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <value>{$imei}</value>\r\n
      </entry>\r\n
      </subscriberProfile>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <subscriberID>123546546</subscriberID>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <alternateId>?</alternateId>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <updateAction>?</updateAction>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <parameter1>?</parameter1>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <parameter2>?</parameter2>\r\n
      </sub:wsUpdateSubscriberProfile>\r\n
      </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>";

    $curl = curl_init();
.....
```

it run successful if the data manually input on the script above. I tried to used dynamic value for the IMEI value from a form within  `$imei = $_POST['86207503'];`

but it doesn't work, the value never passed. Any one know how to solve this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can not reproduce, the imei is definitely injected in this test code:

```
<?php
$imei = 'SOMETHING_EASY_TO_SPOT';   
    $data = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:sub=\"http://subscriberexample.com/\">\r\n
      <soap:Header/>\r\n   <soap:Body>\r\n
      <sub:wsUpdateSubscriberProfile>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <subscriberProfile>\r\n
      <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->\r\n
      <entry>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <key>IMEI</key>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <value>{$imei}</value>\r\n
      </entry>\r\n
      </subscriberProfile>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <subscriberID>123546546</subscriberID>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <alternateId>?</alternateId>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <updateAction>?</updateAction>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <parameter1>?</parameter1>\r\n
      <!--Optional:-->\r\n
      <parameter2>?</parameter2>\r\n
      </sub:wsUpdateSubscriberProfile>\r\n
      </soap:Body>\r\n</soap:Envelope>";
var_dump($data);
```

the output is:

```
string(863) "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:sub="http://subscriberexample.com/">

      <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>

      <sub:wsUpdateSubscriberProfile>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <subscriberProfile>

      <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->

      <entry>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <key>IMEI</key>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <value>SOMETHING_EASY_TO_SPOT</value>

      </entry>

      </subscriberProfile>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <subscriberID>123546546</subscriberID>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <alternateId>?</alternateId>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <updateAction>?</updateAction>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <parameter1>?</parameter1>

      <!--Optional:-->

      <parameter2>?</parameter2>

      </sub:wsUpdateSubscriberProfile>

      </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"
```

and if you look at line 22 in the output, the `$imei` variable is definitely injected. i hence voted to close this question as "can not reproduce".

btw what do you get if you run `var_dump($_POST);` ? is there really a POST variable with the key `86207503` ? if there isn't, it probably means your development environment's `error_reporting` value is bad, means it doesn't include `E_NOTICE`, which it absolutely should

Comment: hi @hansherink, I tried to add var_dump the value not injected, really weird :( it return empty

It only work If I change $imei = '86207503'; manually. If I put the $_POST and the first not working at all

Comment: @Bireon that makes no sense, have you read https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php ?